# Using variable-arity function on values-expression

Tags: racket, arity

I ran into this toy example recently that has me a bit confused. Suppose I define a simple variable-arity function as below. Then, we are totally within our rights to run this both on one argument and on two.

```lisp
(define (my-func . a) a)

(my-func 1)  ; evals to '(1)
(my-func 1 2)  ; evals to '(1 2)
```

The weird bit I've run into is if I try to pass it multiple arguments in one go using `values` as below:

```lisp
(my-func (values 1 2))
```

I'd expect this to evaluate to the same thing as `(my-func 1 2)`, but instead throws an arity-mismatch error, namely that it expected 1 argument but got 2.

Why is it expecting one argument if `my-func` is variable-arity? Does this have to do with the number of syntactic objects as arguments or is it something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Racket, `values` construct multiple **return** values (often abbrev. as multiple values or values). Except the case where it's a single value, values cannot be passed as argument(s). Values can't be kept in a variable. Values are mostly useful when returned from a function, and when used in forms like `define-values`, etc. See [this section](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._values-model%29) of the Racket Reference for more details.

To use the terminology from the above link, `(my-func [])` is a continuation that only accepts a single value. That's why in your program, it errors with the message "expects one, got two".

What you are trying to do can be accomplished with [`call-with-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29):

```
(call-with-values (lambda () (values 1 2)) my-func)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or do:

```
(let-values [(a b) (values 1 2)]
  (my-func a b))
```

Unfortunately one cannot capture variable number of values into one variable.